# SANDBOX REST API: Getting "INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR"

Tags: rest, paypal, paypal-sandbox

Anyone getting "INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR" while using PayPal Sandbox Payment REST API?

Raw response: {"name":"INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR","message":"An internal service error has occurred","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR","debug_id":"19534d4c5d45d"}

Raw response: {"name":"UNKNOWN_ERROR","message":"An unknown error has occurred","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#UNKNOWN_ERROR","debug_id":"47c1243107286"}

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a customer support request, not a question about a programming problem. See [this meta post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-suppo‌​rt-for-your-favorite-company) for more information.

Comment: Check your request and make sure its "correct" - when I hit that type of error during debugging, "something" wasn't right with the request I was sending (e.g. missing param, authentication, token, etc.)

Comment: It may not be particularly well set-out but this question and the response by the original poster represent a problem in the use of the API, with the symptoms and solution which was useful to me. Up-voted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turned out it was just the issue of using the wrong credit card number. When I used the credit card number provided in sandbox text account profile, everything worked.

None of the numbers on this page worked for me.
http://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/vhelp/paypalmanager_help/credit_card_numbers.htm